# Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Contains' is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I am trying to filter a data service using a List, however, I get a few error messages. Is there a way to filter by a List with a DataServiceQuery?

```
DataServiceQuery<Order> ordersQuery = (from x in entities.Orders
                                       .Expand<DataServiceCollection<Shipment>>(a => a.Shipments)
                                       .Expand<DataServiceCollection<OrderItem>>(a => a.OrderItems)
                                       .Expand<OrderStatus>(a => a.OrderStatus)
                                       .Expand<Customer>(a => a.Customer)
                                       .Expand<Store>(a => a.Store)
                                       .Expand<Marketplace>(a => a.Marketplace)
                                       .Expand("Shipments/Carrier")
                                        where  x.OrderStatusID != 4
                                        select x) as DataServiceQuery<Order>;

        if (beginDate != null && endDate != null)
            ordersQuery = ordersQuery.Where(x => x.CreateDate >= beginDate && x.CreateDate <= endDate) as DataServiceQuery<Order>;

        if (statuses != null && statuses.Count() > 0)
        ordersQuery = ordersQuery.Where(a => stores.Contains(a.OrderStatus.Name)) as DataServiceQuery<Order>;

        if (stores != null && stores.Count() > 0)
            ordersQuery = ordersQuery.Where(a => stores.Contains(a.Store.StoreName)) as DataServiceQuery<Order>;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orderNumber))
            ordersQuery = ordersQuery.Where(a => a.OrderNumber == orderNumber) as DataServiceQuery<Order>;
```

That code fails with

*Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Contains' is not supported.*

This code also fails:

```
 if (statuses != null && statuses.Count() > 0)

        {
            var statusFilterList = statuses.Select(title => String.Format("(Name eq {0})", title));
            var statusFilter = String.Join(" or ", statusFilterList);
            ordersQuery.AddQueryOption("$filter", statusFilter).Execute().ToList();

        }
```

*Can't add query option '$filter' because it would conflict with the query options from the translated Linq expression.*

Comment: Yes, use a loop and `PredicateBuilder`. But you can easily exceed URL length limit.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the for loop in this case?